# monacaでローカルにテキストドキュメント（.txt）を残しそれを読み書きしたいです。

Tags: ios, monaca, jquery, html5

monacaにサンプルでメモアプリがありますが、ローカル（ios上）にテキストドキュメントを残していないようなのでファイルをFileRead/Writeするような形でメモアプリを作成したいです。

htmlは

```
<textarea id="text" placeholder="テキストを入力してください。"></textarea>
<br />
<button id="btndownWrite">ファイル作成/書き込み</button>
<button id="btndownRead">ファイル読み込み</button>
```

というのを考えており、
とりあえずでいいので
btndownWriteを押したらローカルにファイル（テキストドキュメント[.txt]）を作成しtextの文字を書き込む（すでにあったら追記する）、
btndownReadを押したらローカルにあるファイル（テキストドキュメント[.txt]）をtextに表示する。
ようなものを作りたいです。

無知ですがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordovaのファイルプラグインというものを使って実現できますので、まずはご自身でもう少しお調べになってみてください。下記ページなどが参考になると思います。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/file/
http://gihyo.jp/dev/serial/01/phonegap2/0004

Comment: citherさんありがとうございます。もう少し調べて見ます。